# How to pass variable in bat command without showing it's value on console in jenkinsfile

Tags: windows, jenkins, cmd, jenkins-pipeline

I am running the below command in Jenkinsfile and it shows the password on console I want to mask or hide the password.

```
bat 'powershell.exe -File "file.ps1" -password "%PWD%"'
```

In Jenkinsfile I tried this also but it's passing the * only not value

```
wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[password: 'thePassword', var: 'PWD']]]) {
                        bat 'powershell.exe -File "file.ps1" -password "thePassword"'
                    }
```

Comment: `cmd /V /C bat 'powershell.exe -File "file.ps1" -password "!PWD!"'`?

Answer (score 1):

Please use [Jenkins Credential Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) and add the credentials in Jenkins and use them in your Jenkinsfile by using below code:-

```
 withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'mylogin', variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
    bat '''
      powershell.exe -File "file.ps1" -password "%USERPASS%"
    '''
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I don't want to use credentials functionality I am reading the password from aws secret manager and I am looking at how can I mask password here itself.

Comment: You can also just have the PowerShell script file.ps1 use $env:USERPASS instead of even passing it on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Credentials functionality of jenkins.
Then you can use the step, withCredentails, which hides you secrets.